# Use jquery to get jsondata

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use .getJSON to get data from server. The data can get, but it can not display in page.

js code:

```
$(function(){ 
    alert(1);
      $("#jsondata").bind("click",function()
      { 
          var data = "action=getdata";
          alert(2);
          $.getJSON("Guess.php",data, function(json)
          {  
              alert(3);
              var str = '<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>1#Sex</td><td>2#Tel</td></tr>';
              $.each(json,function(i,v){
                  str += '<tr><td>'+v.name+'</td><td>'+v.sex+'</td><td>'+v.tel+'</td></tr>';
              });
              str += '</table>';
              $("#datashow").append(str);
         });  
      }); 
  });
```

html code:

```
    <button id="jsondata" name="jsondata" accesskey="g">GetData</button>
<div id="datashow"></div>
```

The data I got from server display in fire bug:
{"name":"Tom","sex":"male","tel":"456","email":"sdfd@15.com"}

Comment: If `json` response variable is not array of object its pointless to iterate with `$.each`.

Comment: Did you try to alert str? If it has the proper HTML data then try  $("#datashow").html(str); instead of append

Comment: Actually before that the alert(3) didn't work. I don't why..

Answer (score 1):

The json parameter for success function should already be parsed as JSON, so loop with a normal loop:

```
$(function(){ 
    alert(1);
      $("#jsondata").bind("click",function()
      { 
          var data = "action=getdata";
          alert(2);
          $.getJSON("Guess.php",data, function(json)
          {  
              alert(3);
              var str = '<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>1#Sex</td><td>2#Tel</td></tr>';
              for(var i in json) {
                  str += '<tr><td>' + i.name + '</td><td>' + i.sex + '</td><td>' + i.tel + '</td></tr>';
              }
              str += '</table>';
              $("#datashow").append(str);
         });  
      }); 
  });
```

Comment: Sounds like the response from the server is the wrong format, so the success function is not called. Try adding an error function in $.ajax() or check your Guess.php response is printing correct JSON syntax.

Comment: Yes, format is wrong. I use php json_encode($data) to response, but why the format is wrong?

Comment: Can you post your response?

Comment: I find the problem, before display the data, there are some other output like php notice information. So I close the notice info, the problem solved....

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (There is no need to loop with `$.each`)

```
$(function () {
        $("#jsondata").bind("click", function () {
            var data = "action=getdata";
            $.getJSON("Guess.php", data, function (json) {
                var str = '<table><tr><td>日期</td><td>1#铸机产量</td><td>2#铸机产量</td></tr>';
                str += '<tr><td>' + json.name + '</td><td>' + json.sex + '</td><td>' + json.tel + '</td></tr>';
                str += '</table>';
                $("#datashow").append(str);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Before the code [var str] , I add a alert(3), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
      $.getJSON("Guess.php",data, function(json) {  

          // Convert json reponse object to array
          json = $.makeArray(json);

          var str = '<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>1#Sex</td><td>2#Tel</td></tr>';
          $.each(json,function(i,v){
              str += '<tr><td>'+v.name+'</td><td>'+v.sex+'</td><td>'+v.tel+'</td></tr>';
          });
          str += '</table>';
          $("#datashow").append(str);
     });  
  });
```